# Identify disk manufacturer in Macbook Air

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, ssd, macos

I wonder how can I know which is the disk's manufacturer for my Macbook Air. Is there a way to know whether the disk is one of those faulty SSD disk that [Apple has recalled](http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/18/4853430/apple-recalls-last-years-macbook-air-due-to-faulty-ssd-drives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article which you linked to from the Verge says there is a [firmware update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1690) on the app store which will test your drive.  If your firmware cannot be updated Apple will replace your drive for free.

I would back up my data and run the mentioned firmware update.

I could not find the firmware update on the app store but I found it on the Apple support site [here.](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1690)

Comment: I downloaded and ran the update and it shows an alert saying "This computer does not need this update", can I be 100% sure that my disk is not a faulty one?

Comment: Yes.  However the proviso is "it depends on how much you trust Apple".  Just because your SSD does not have that particular fault does not mean it may not develop one in the future or have another as yet unidentified one.  But yes, I would say you can be sure that your disk is not the one being recalled.